# How to enable the memcached PHP extension after installing with homebrew?

Tags: php, macos, memcached, homebrew

I recently installed memcached with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), I'm not entirely sure how to enable it on my PHP envirionment since I added `extension=memcached.so` in `/etc/php.ini` in Lion OS X.

Even I restarted apache too, nothing is still loaded.

If I call `get_loaded_extensions()`, I do not see memcached in the list, how can I enable it when installed from homebrew?

EDIT:

What I did in Terminal was:

`$ brew install memcached`

It installed just fine, now I went to `/etc/php.ini` and appended:

`extension=memcached.so`

Comment: What does your PHP error log state about the `extension` command you have given?

Comment: There's no extension command. I can see in my error log: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcached.so'`

Comment: That's the explanation: PHP is unable to load the library file you've provided. Can be that the file does not exists, can be that the file is just not compatible.

Comment: But the reason I'm asking, is to how to make the installed memcached work with PHP?

Comment: See my answer. If you can provide more information, more information can be given. But as long as you don't, it's not possible at all. I don't know what you did, so it's necessary to stick to the factual information you can provide. For example the error message, see my answer.

Comment: It's worth noting for others that find this, at least at the moment, the memcached pecl module won't compile for php 5.4 or 5.5. Readers in the future: check the status of this ticket https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65134

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcached.so'`

That's the information PHP is giving you, stick to it.

It's either:

- The file you have specified does not exists. Check your file-system.
- The file you've specified can not be read by PHP, check the rights of the file.
- The file you've specified is incompatible with your PHP binary. Check if you have compiled the right sources and compilation went well.

Comment: I don't know how to give you more information, check my edit.

Comment: Have you installed php with homebrew as well? And is the .so file inside the directory PHP expects it to be?

Comment: No, I'm using the PHP that came with Lion OS X by default. There is no `memcached.so` in the directory.

Comment: There is actually *no* `memcached.so` around my MacBook, I tried searching with the `find` command and didn't find it at all.

Comment: Then first [install the memcache PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.installation.php) (next to the server). Without the actual binary of the extension, it's obvious, that it does not work, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm. I fixed the problem, I first installed libmemcached via homebrew then installed memcached with pecl.

Answer (score 46):

Install Memcached:

```
# lists all memcached related packages
brew search memcached

# install memcached as well as memcached extension for PHP
brew install memcached
brew install php54-memcached

# start memcached daemon with 24MB on port 11211 (default)
memcached -d -m 24 -p 11211
```

Add to your `php.ini` file to add:

```
extension=memcached.so
```

Restart php or php5-fpm and your server. Verify:

```
php -i | grep memcached
# should show memcached version, etc.
```

Comment: This was what I was missing: `brew install php55-memcached`

Comment: It now seems as adding "extension=memcached.so" is not needed as php on startup says "Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini" which has that line in it.

Comment: The above installation works for CLI but with Apache it is not working. Any idea how to fix for apache I am trying to add additional ini in apache but not effective either. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Install:

```
brew install memcached
OR
sudo pecl install memcached
```

Add this line to /etc/php.ini:

```
extension = memcached.so
OR
extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcached.so"
```

If you are having trouble finding where it lives do

```
mdfind memcached.so -name
=> /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcached.so
```

Make sure it is running as a daemon (-d):

```
/usr/local/bin/memcached -d
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Installed and got error about autoconf. Next person who reads this, install autoconf by using *brew install autoconf*

Comment: what is autoconf?

Comment: @user269867 -   http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to install libmemcached with homebrew, not just memcached.  Do this:

```
brew install libmemcached
```

Then try recompiling your memcache PHP module.  Should be good to go

Comment: And how would you "recompile your memcache PHP module" then?

Comment: `brew reinstall memcached`

Comment: In fact libmemcached was my issue as well. I had already installed it, so when I tried `brew install libmemcached` brew said Warning: libmemcached-1.0.18_1 already installed, it's just not linked. So I ran brew link libmemcached and then there was a permissions issue on /usr/local/include so I chown -R that folder to my user and then brew link ran fine, and then the extension worked, the error went away and my site loaded just fine.

Answer (score 11):

First, install memcached library with:

```
sudo pecl install memcached
```

Then, add this line to `/etc/php.ini`:

```
extension = memcached.so
```

That's it.

Answer (score 4):

In Mac OS X El Capitan you can use

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-memcached
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install the memcache.so module the following way:

```
brew install memcached-php
```

(Note the above is currently broken if you don't have the right Xcode version)

Then go to your php.ini file and add the following (Replace VERSION with the correct value):

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/memcached-php/VERSION/memcached.so"
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

If you can't figure out which php.ini file is being used, try calling the phpinfo() command.  It will tell you exactly which php.ini file it's using.

Comment: This answers your question better. You think you've installed the php extension for memcached but have only installed memcached itself.

Comment: `brew install memcached-php` gives `Error: No available formula for memcached-php`

Comment: what is the correct version of xcode needed for this? will it work with 3.2.6?

Comment: Try: brew install php54-memcached (or php53 if you are on 5.3)

Comment: Tap: `brew tap homebrew/dupes;brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php` (see https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php ) then `brew install php55-memcached` (or whatever version you're using).